# Rotate background using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HTML**

```
<div class="selectContainer">
            <ul>
                <li class="init" id="init">Select</li>
                <li data-value="value 1">Option 1</li>
                <li data-value="value 2">Option 2</li>
                <li data-value="value 3">Option 3</li>                                                            
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.init { cursor: pointer; background:url("../images/arrow-down.png") right no-repeat; }
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul").click(function () {
        $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').slideToggle(200);
    });
    $('.init').on('click', function () {
        $(".init").css({
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + 180 + 'deg)'
        });
    });
});
```

hi, I just want the down-arrow image to be upside down. I Use transform ".init" class but the whole class is rotating i just need only background image to be rotated.

Comment: Milind Anantwar i could not find how to change it... dont make it duplicate

Comment: have you checked the answers provided for marked as duplicate question??

Comment: Milind Anantwar ya checked but not like that i need 
"$(".init").css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + 180 + 'deg)'});"
how to select background alone exactly

Comment: You can not do that. try the provided solutions from marked question.

Comment: we cant make select background image and rotate it??

Comment: No you can not. see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vpTR6/.